# Are the app store review guidelines under NDA?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, development

To access the app store review guidelines you need to sign in:
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Does that mean they are under NDA or it it ok to blog about a specific requirement?

Answer (score 2):

There have been several cases of people blogging about review guidelines, and AFAIK, nowhere does Apple ask us to agree to an NDA about the guidelines when creating our developer account (at least, they didn't for me).

Here's a few cases of the guidelines being blogged about:

[iClarified](http://www.iclarified.com/24389/apple-updates-app-store-review-guidelines-tells-developers-to-prepare-for-ios-6), [LocalMediaInsider](http://www.localmediainsider.com/stories/Apple-Store-Review-Guidelines-for-new-apps-,734), [ReadWrite](http://readwrite.com/2012/10/05/making-sense-of-the-fud-around-apples-app-store-clause-225), [engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2010/09/09/apples-app-store-review-guidelines-we-dont-need-any-more-far/)

Comment: Although I agree that I don't think there is any NDA saying other people have done it isn't really proof. Other people murder people but that doesn't mean murdering is legal.

Comment: @Tony I also mentioned that AFAIK, we were not required to sign an NDA for this when registering our developer accounts. At least I wasnt.